# firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword exposes my password

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

New to firebase.

I wonder why my email and password is shown after I sign in using the `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword` method.
Any ideas why?

[image]
Appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It exposes your password because it has to send it to the server. But note that it is sent over a secure connection, so nobody but your browser and the server will be able to see it.